# Android change View width inside of onDraw

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a `ListView` where there will be columns of data which will be aligned vertically and have to update when new items are added. There is a `LinearLayout` above the `ListView` with `TextView`s acting as a header which will also need to have their width change to maintain the alignment.

The `ListView` updates properly when items are added, but the header does not.

The header only seems to update when the onscreen keyboard is pulled in or pushed out of view, either by clicking on the `EditText` widget or hitting the back button.

I created a wrapper class for `TextView` where a few of the functions make a call to the `Log` class before and after `super.whatever()` in order to determine what is being called and when.

From this, I can see that when an item is added to the `ListView`, and the widths need to be changed, only the `setWidth()` and `onDraw()` are being called.

While inside the `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` I have tried making calls to the header `TextView`s things like `invalidate()`, `postInvalidate()`, and to the `LinearLayout` holding the headers additional things like `childDrawableStateChanged()`. I have tried to use `setLayoutParams()` instead of `setWidth()`. With or without these functions, the application performs identically.

How do I tell the `TextView`s to read their new widths before drawing, but while inside the `getView` of the `ArrayAddapter`?

Sample code is to display a `ListView` with 2 simple text items where the add `Button` will insert the text from the `EditText` into column 1 and "b" into column 2. the settings `Button` was to test effects of `onPause` and `onResume`.

```
package testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.testing.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    TestArrayAdapter testAA;
    private MyTextView headerA, headerB;
    private LinearLayout headerLine;
    private EditText inputEditText;
    private Button addButton, settingsButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        // get views and setup custom headers
        inputEditText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.inputEditText);
        addButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        settingsButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        headerLine = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.headerLineLayout);
        headerA = (MyTextView) new MyTextView(this);
        headerA.setText("H1");
        headerB = (MyTextView) new MyTextView(this);
        headerB.setText("H2");
        headerLine.addView(headerA);
        headerLine.addView(headerB);

        // get initial header width to set as max width
        int headerWidthA = (int) headerA.getPaint().measureText((String) headerA.getText());
        int headerWidthB = (int) headerB.getPaint().measureText((String) headerB.getText());

        // most likely redundant
        headerA.setWidth(headerWidthA);
        headerB.setWidth(headerWidthB);

        // setup listeners and adapter
        testAA = new TestArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.main_layout_line, new StringList());
        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.setListAdapter(testAA);

        // set header widths as initial max width
        testAA.strList.maxWidthA = headerWidthA;
        testAA.strList.maxWidthB = headerWidthB;

        Log.i("main", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("main", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == this.findViewById(R.id.addButton))
            testAA.add(new StringLine(inputEditText.getText().toString()));
        if (view == this.findViewById(R.id.settingsButton))
            this.startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
    }

    class TestArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StringLine> {

        private StringList strList;

        public TestArrayAdapter(Context context, int res, StringList strList) {
            super(context, res, strList.items);
            this.strList = strList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.i("testAA", "getView start");
            // inflate row view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout_line, parent, false);

            // get items and set their text
            TextView itemA = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemText1);
            TextView itemB = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemText2);
            itemA.setText(strList.items.get(pos).a);
            itemB.setText(strList.items.get(pos).b);

            // determine the width of the text and if the header needs to be updated
            int itemWidthA = (int) itemA.getPaint().measureText((String) itemA.getText());
            if (itemWidthA <= strList.maxWidthA) {
                itemWidthA = strList.maxWidthA;
            } else {
                Log.i("testAA", "header changed");
                strList.maxWidthA = itemWidthA;
                headerA.setWidth(itemWidthA);
                // TELL HEADER TO REDRAW HERE
                headerA.invalidate();
                headerA.postInvalidate();
                headerLine.invalidate();
                headerLine.postInvalidate();
                headerLine.childDrawableStateChanged(headerA);
                testAA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            itemA.setWidth(itemWidthA);

            Log.i("testAA", "getView end");
            return rowView;
        }
    }

    // list of for the array adapter
    class StringList {
        ArrayList<StringLine> items = new ArrayList<StringLine>();
        int maxWidthA, maxWidthB;

    }

    // line item for array adapter list
    class StringLine {
        public StringLine(String stringA) {
            a = stringA;
            b = "b";
        }

        String a, b;
    }

    // wrapper class 
    class MyTextView extends TextView {

        public MyTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Log.i("header", "onDraw start " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Log.i("header", "onDraw end " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            Log.i("header", "onMeasure start " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            Log.i("header", "onMeasure end " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            Log.i("header", "layout start " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
            super.layout(l, t, r, b);
            Log.i("header", "layout end " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        public void setWidth(int width) {
            Log.i("header", "setWidth start " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
            super.setWidth(width);
            Log.i("header", "setWidth end " + this.getText() + " width - " + this.getWidth());
        }
    }

}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLineLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_layout_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat (H1 needs to have a width of 60 after the item has been added to the `ListView`)

```
application started
04-28 17:53:54.614: E/Trace(2780): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 17:53:55.394: D/dalvikvm(2780): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 7% free 2677K/2872K, paused 24ms, total 26ms
04-28 17:53:55.394: I/dalvikvm-heap(2780): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.336MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-28 17:53:55.424: D/dalvikvm(2780): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 6% free 3294K/3496K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
04-28 17:53:55.464: D/dalvikvm(2780): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3305K/3496K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 36ms
04-28 17:53:55.484: I/header(2780): setWidth start H1 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.484: I/header(2780): setWidth end H1 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.484: I/header(2780): setWidth start H2 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.484: I/header(2780): setWidth end H2 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.494: I/main(2780): onCreate
04-28 17:53:55.494: I/main(2780): onResume
04-28 17:53:55.564: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.574: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.574: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.574: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.614: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.614: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.614: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 0
04-28 17:53:55.614: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.654: D/gralloc_goldfish(2780): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-28 17:53:55.684: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.684: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.694: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.694: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.904: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.904: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.904: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.954: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.954: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.954: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.954: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:55.954: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.254: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.254: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.254: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.264: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.304: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.304: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.304: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.304: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.314: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.314: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.314: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.314: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.364: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.364: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.364: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.374: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.624: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.624: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.634: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.634: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.654: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.654: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.654: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.664: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.685: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.685: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.704: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.704: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.754: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.754: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.764: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.764: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.794: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.794: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.794: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.794: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.844: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.844: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.844: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.844: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.844: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.855: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.855: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.855: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.884: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.884: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.894: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:53:56.894: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
text entered and clicked add
04-28 17:54:29.965: I/testAA(2780): getView start
04-28 17:54:29.975: I/testAA(2780): header changed
04-28 17:54:29.975: I/header(2780): setWidth start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:29.975: I/header(2780): setWidth end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:29.975: I/testAA(2780): getView end
04-28 17:54:29.985: I/testAA(2780): getView start
04-28 17:54:29.995: I/testAA(2780): getView end
04-28 17:54:30.005: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.005: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.005: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.005: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.035: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.045: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.045: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:30.045: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
clicked Back Button to lower keyboard
04-28 17:54:56.755: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.755: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.765: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.765: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.765: I/testAA(2780): getView start
04-28 17:54:56.795: I/testAA(2780): getView end
04-28 17:54:56.865: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.875: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.875: I/header(2780): onMeasure start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.875: I/header(2780): onMeasure end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.875: I/testAA(2780): getView start
04-28 17:54:56.885: I/testAA(2780): getView end
04-28 17:54:56.895: I/header(2780): layout start H1 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.925: I/header(2780): layout end H1 width - 60
04-28 17:54:56.925: I/header(2780): layout start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.925: I/header(2780): layout end H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.985: I/header(2780): onDraw start H1 width - 60
04-28 17:54:56.985: I/header(2780): onDraw end H1 width - 60
04-28 17:54:56.985: I/header(2780): onDraw start H2 width - 27
04-28 17:54:56.995: I/header(2780): onDraw end H2 width - 27
header updated
```